# National University of Singapore admission test

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, acceleration, projectile

Can someone help me with this awful question? Thanks.

A ball is thrown from a point P on a cliff of height h meters above the seashore. It strikes the shore at a point Q, where PQ is inclined at an angle α below the horizontal. If the angle of projection is also α, show that the speed of projection is (sqrt(gh))/(2 sin α) ms-1, where g is the acceleration due to gravity. Prove also that the ball strikes the shore at an angle arctan( 3tan α) with the horizontal. [image]

Comment: Hi Pey and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I suggest typing in \latex, it makes for much easier reading for the rest of us and will be a valuable skill in your future endeavours!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All you have to do is figure out the time and all falls in place. The horizontal component is vcosα and the horizontal distance is hcotα. Dividing them, you get the time as h/sinα. Put this in the equation $-h=vsinαt-1/2gt^2$. This gives you the vertical component as sqrt(gh)/2 and this gives you the required answer.

For, the second part, use the equation $v^2=u^2+2gh$ to get the final vertical velocity, which turns out to be thrice initial vertical velocity. Horizontal component remains same and hence the final tan is thrice the initial tan giving you the second answer.

Comment: Did you not just put a link on typesetting in another post? Cheers :)